# Possible to get feed data?

Tags: spotify

Is it possible with the public app API to get data such as when a friend finish playing a track, when a friend adds a track to a playlist etc? Like the Feed app(spotify:app:feed).

The feed app seems to be doing something like this:

```
var presenceEvents = react.fromDOMEvent(sp.core, "hermes"); 

presenceEvents.subscribe(function(e) {
    console.log(sp.core.parseHermesReply("PresenceState", e.data[1]));
}
```

(This code by the way don't work as intended but seems this is the way to do it. Not all events are caught)

Is it okay to do it in this way, or will it not be accepted into App finder? Is it possible to do it using the documented apps API classes? I can't find anything for this in the documentation, is there anything undocumented I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EVERYTHING not in the public documentation will cause you to be rejected from the App Finder, which includes EVERYTHING under sp.core.

Please only use the publicly documented API methods when writing Spotify applications. In addition, the APIs you're posting are private and won't work in your application.

To be clear, the feed data will *never* be available to your Spotify application in any form, for privacy reasons. The reason your code doesn't work is because of this restriction.

Comment: if the data feed is not available in the spotify API, how can this application retrieve what users play? https://www.spotify.com/uk/arts/serendipity/?ref=producthunt

Comment: 1) That app isn't using the App API, which is what this question is about and has long since been discontinued entirely, 2) If you look at the about text of that app you'll see it's written by a Spotify employee. Obviously, Spotify has data available to it that isn't public, and 3) if you further read the about text you'll see it's not live data, and it's not "friends" data. Thanks for the downvote, though!

Comment: after your reply I wish i could upvote again but stack overflow does not allows me to do it unless the reply is edited. I agree with your points but I'm not sure he is allowed to access private data.

Comment: He is a Spotify employee, as am I. We definitely get access to richer APIs than the public ones — it'd be hard to impossible to build the clients if we didn't.